# Why is useContext() not returning the Provider value instead returning the initial value?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-context

```
import React, { useContext, createContext } from "react";

const messageContext = createContext("Hello");

const Context = () => {

    const message = useContext(messageContext);

    return (
        <messageContext.Provider value="Hi">

            <div style={{ marginTop: 1000 }}>{message}</div> 
            {/* Result: Hello */}

            <messageContext.Consumer>
                {message => {
                    return <div style={{ marginTop: 1000 }}>{message}</div>;
                }}
            </messageContext.Consumer>
            {/* Result: Hi */}

        </messageContext.Provider>
    );
};
export { Context };
```

I want to use the **useContext()** hook but it always returns the initial value which is "**Hello**".

Using **<messageContext.Consumer>** has no problem. It returns "**Hi**" but i want  to use the useContext hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you grab something from context, you get it from the nearest provider **up** the component tree. Since you called useContext inside the `Context` component, it will look for a provider higher up the tree than `Context`. None exists, so you get the default value instead. Your example with the `messageContext.Consumer` is inside a provider, so it can see that value.

There's little reason to consume a value in the exact same component where you provide it. In order to provide the value you presumably have some logic which results in a local variable, and you can reuse that same local variable for any other parts of the component that need it.